# How to change Apache Tomcat default error page values?

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-code

I'm currently using a Spring Boot application I'm tinkering around the the error page and the messages given to it. Currently I can change the HTTP Status Number and Message, but I'm not sure how to change the "Unknown reason" or Description without changing it to something besides 418. Is there a way to customize those as well, or am I stuck with the embedded code provide?

Current Code Tinkering

```
for(String serialNo : serialNoList) {
    if(serialNo.length() < MIN_SERIALNO_SIZE ) {
        response.sendError(401, "Serial Number Length Exceeded: " + serialNo);
    }
    if(serialNo.length() > MAX_SERIALNO_SIZE) {
        response.sendError(403, "Serial Number Legth Too Short: " + serialNo);
    }
}
```

[image: Error Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to disable whiteLabel error pages.

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

or

```
// adding this on your main class 
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Now, create a html page (**error.html**), which you want to display and place it in `resources/templates` directory, it will be picked automatically.

To `customize`, differently for each error you can implement `ErrorController`.

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {
   
   // override this error path to custom error path
   @Override
   public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/custom-error";
   }

   @GetMapping("/custom-error")
   public String customHandling(HttpServletRequest request){
       // you can use request to get different error codes
       // request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE)

       // you can return different `view` based on error codes.
       // return 'error-404' or 'error-500' based on errors
   }
}
```