# How to mask Apache Version on Error Page of Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application with embedded tomcat , whenever there is a server error occurs, I want to hide the apache tomcat version on error page.

As far as I know; the most known solutions are adding server.properties to web.xml or zipping the catalina jar.

Since the application does not have web.xml, I can't figure it out to hide tomcat version.

Tomcat server properties were changed as below but none of them worked.

- server.error.include-stacktrace=never
- server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

Spring boot version : **2.5.4**

Please refer the picture.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Apache Tomcat default error page values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947601/how-to-change-apache-tomcat-default-error-page-values)

Comment: Since It's enforcing to create a custom error page and only handle the error response codes, that is not the answer for me, thanks.

Comment: Please add the full screenshot not a snippet as well as specify **which version** of Spring Boot you are using.

Comment: I edited my question and added the full screenshot, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with spring boot, but with Tomcat. See the "marked as duplicate" link on how to deal with Tomcat.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't look to have anything to do with Spring Boot nor with an embedded tomcat. So trying to manage an external tomcat from within an application will obviously not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For embedded tomcat, I found configuration to override error report valve

Now the response does not have tomcat version.

```
var host = (StandardHost) tomcat.getHost();

var errorReportValve = new org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve();
errorReportValve.setShowReport(false);
errorReportValve.setShowServerInfo(false);
host.addValve(errorReportValve);
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be same issue as following:

- [Allow custom ErrorReportValve to be used with Tomcat and provide whitelabel version #21257](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21257)

---

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve;
import org.apache.coyote.ActionCode;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils;

public class CustomErrorReportValve extends ErrorReportValve {

    // Create a simple logger
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomErrorReportValve.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void report(final Request request, final Response response, final Throwable throwable) {
        // ref: ErrorReportValve implementation

        final int statusCode = response.getStatus();

        // Do nothing on a 1xx, 2xx and 3xx status
        // Do nothing if anything has been written already
        // Do nothing if the response hasn't been explicitly marked as in error
        //    and that error has not been reported.
        if (statusCode < 400 || response.getContentWritten() > 0 || !response.setErrorReported()) {
            return;
        }

        // If an error has occurred that prevents further I/O, don't waste time
        // producing an error report that will never be read
        final AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        response.getCoyoteResponse().action(ActionCode.IS_IO_ALLOWED, result);
        if (!result.get()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            try {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            } catch (final Throwable t) {
                ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(t);
                if (container.getLogger().isDebugEnabled()) {
                    container.getLogger().debug("status.setContentType", t);
                }
            }
            final Writer writer = response.getReporter();
            if (writer != null) {
                // If writer is null, it's an indication that the response has
                // been hard committed already, which should never happen
                writer.write("<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><title>error</title><body>Error occured.</body></html>");
                response.finishResponse();
            }
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import org.apache.catalina.Container;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyConfig {
    // https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-legacycookieprocessor
    // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21257#issuecomment-745565376
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> errorReportValveCustomizer() {

        return (factory) -> {
            factory.addContextCustomizers(context -> {
                final Container parent = context.getParent();
                if (parent instanceof StandardHost) {
                    // above class FQCN
                    ((StandardHost) parent).setErrorReportValveClass(
                        "com.example.foo.bar.CustomErrorReportValve");
                }
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same trouble to prevent Spring disclosing technical informations about our backend implementation

Here is how I've configured the server part in order to restrict to the strict minimum what is returned to the user, without having to deal with writing a custom Tomcat error page myself :

```yaml
server:
  # On Spring Boot default implementation, whenever a REST API is called with
  # an "Accept : Html" header, a 406 status is replied to the user thanks the Spring
  # default error management mechanism : its Html whitelable page.
  # The drawback of this default error page is that it easily disclose sensitive
  # technical information about your backend implementation :
  #  - error stack trace, revealing the use of Spring
  #  - the embedded tomcat's version, which help framing Spring version ...
  # To change the default error management configuration you can do the following :
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false # error management fallback on Tomcat default error page
    # To prevent Tomcat's default error page disclosing information :
    include-binding-errors: never
    include-message: never
    include-stacktrace: never # most important one : prevent Tomcat version disclose
    include-exception: false
```