# Spring boot 2.7.+ tomcat server version disclosure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat9

I have a spring boot web application, but on error server info is exposed. Based on my research I can disclose it by putting custom context.xml and I tried to place it in src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml and src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml. I see that context.xml is included in the jar in META-INF but is not taken into account in my opinion as server info is still present.

I am using embedded Tomcat within Spring Boot.

Can you please help with forcing spring boot to consume custom tomcat context.xml?

Comment: Are you deploying a war file to Tomcat or using Tomcat embedded within your Spring Boot application?

Comment: embedded tomcat

Comment: brilliant, thank you!

Comment: I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516916/9341865 and working now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure but check if in the server.xml file you have the override attribute of the  element set to true